# Laravel Get Headers From Route Group Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

Im trying to get the header values from request get/post in my middleware, but I cant get it.

In my AdminMiddleware I was trying to get the value this way

**AdminToken.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null) {
     ...
     return response()->json($request->input('ADMIN_TOKEN')); //not returning header value
```

**Kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminToken::class,
```

**api.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']], function() {
    ...
```

[image: Postman test]

Thank you so much everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in your controller :

```
dd($request->header('ADMIN_TOKEN'));
```

Answer (score 0):

i found solution if somenone else needs.

**AdminToken.php**

```
use Request;// import required

Request::header('ADMIN_TOKEN') // function to get header
```